# gfortran: Namelist and variable initialization

Tags: gfortran, intel-fortran

I am porting from ifort to gfortran and having trouble with the following code:

```
MODULE test
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL*8 :: a

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE load
  a = 0.0d0
  NAMELIST /materialProperties/ a
END SUBROUTINE load

END MODULE test
```

I will get a compiler error about the namelist. Anyhow, if the variable initialization is disabled (a=0.0d0 commented), than the error disappears. This is not in the Intel compiler and I am wondering why this is.

Comment: We are wondering what the error message from gfortran is.  How do you think that it isn't an important aid to diagnosing the problem with your code and why are you withholding it from us ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in defining the `NAMELIST` *after* giving the variable `a` a value. As you saw, deleting/commenting that line removes the error, but so does moving the declaration of `a` into `SUBROUTINE load`.

My guess is that `ifort` ignores that line while `gfortran` does not.

Comment: The Intel Fortran compiler documentation indicates that non-standard positioning of `namelist` statements is allowed.  I don't think that ifort ignores the assignment to `a`, rather it doesn't complain about the non-standard positioning of the `namelist` statement.  The compiler option `-warn stderrors` will smoke out this (type of) mistake.